# Webservice Call works with Debugger, but not standalone

Tags: android, json, web-services, debugging, android-studio

I develop a simple App with a web service call, getting json objects etc.

If I started the App with the Debugger (in Android Studio) and debug the app, the call to the Webservice working, I got my values back, all fine.

But if I start the App away from the Debugger, just from the Launcher, I press the Button to perform the call, but nothing happen (just the Text from the "onPostExecute()-Method" is showing).

What do I wrong, or which parameter I must set to run the app standalone?

Info: The Internet-Permission is included

Comment: please post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

try after setting ConnectionTimeout as max value like below

```
int timeoutConnection = 40000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
```

also ensure that You written code other than main thread.

Comment: ah, damit I found the misstake >.< In my Code, there was "Debug.waitingForDebugger()"... now it wokrs :/